# Wrong value into my controller

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc

when I retrieves  my setting  'email' from my html page in my controller Spring I do not receive my entire string

***my js:***

```
modalNode.find('.modal-btn-yes').click(function () {
                var email =  document.getElementById('email');
                location.href = $(this).data('url') + "/" + encodeURI(email.value);
            });
```

***my controller:***

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/compile/{applicationId}/{email}")
    public String compileApplication(@PathVariable Long applicationId, @PathVariable String email) throws ApplicationNotFoundException {
    ...
}
```

***my value input in my html page:***

> myemail@gmail.com

***my value in my controller:***

> myemail@gmail

Comment: To which URL does this code send you? Does that contain the .com part?

Comment: I don't know if it'll fix anything, but usually you use `encodeURIComponent()` instead of `encodeURI()` for something like this

Comment: @rje No that doesn't contain the .com part

Comment: Well that at least means the problem is in the JavaScript code. Try checking what email.value is.

Comment: in the js email.value is good i have the good value

Comment: @Xstian yes my Variable is truncat